# Manually scroll to add class doesn't work here

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is JSFiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/asif097/HHEqx/

Hi there,

in the link above you will find when a link is clicked a class `active` is getting added on `('.nav-inner a')`,  In the mean time the page also scrolls. (see code for more understanding):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".target1").offset().top
    }, 1000);

    $('#link1').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".target1").offset().top
        }, 1000);
        $('.nav-inner a').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
    $('#link2').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".target2").offset().top,
        }, 1000);
        $('.nav-inner a').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
    $('#link3').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(".target3").offset().top
        }, 1000);
        $('.nav-inner a').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });

});
```

**Now** I want this to happen, when I manually scroll addClass() run the same way. Tried this one:

```
    $('html, body').scroll(function ()
{
    if(($('html, body').scrollTop())<1000)
    {
        $(".nav-inner a").removeClass('active');
        $(".nav-inner a:nth-child(1)").addClass('active');
    }
    else if(($('html, body').scrollTop())<2000)
    {
        $(".nav-inner a").removeClass('active');
        $(".nav-inner a:nth-child(2)").addClass('active');
    }
    else
    {
        $(".nav-inner a").removeClass('active');
        $(".nav-inner a:nth-child(3)").addClass('active');
    }
});
```

**But**, doesn't work. Can any one fix my code? (Explanation is expected)

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/HHEqx/4/

```
$(window).scroll(function (){
    var scrll = $(this).scrollTop();
    if(scrll < 1000)
    {
        $(".nav-inner a").removeClass('active');
        $(".nav-inner a:nth-child(1)").addClass('active');
    }
    else if(scrll < 2000)
    {
        $(".nav-inner a").removeClass('active');
        $(".nav-inner a:nth-child(2)").addClass('active');
    }
    else
    {
        $(".nav-inner a").removeClass('active');
        $(".nav-inner a:nth-child(3)").addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `$('html, body').scroll()` with `$(window).scroll()`

And `$('html, body').scrollTop()` with `$(window).scrollTop()`

Check it out : [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HHEqx/3/)